# Variations - not working with new pages

Tags: variations, pages

I am experiencing some issues with variations in Sharepoint Online. We have two sites; nl-nl, which is the source and en-us, which is the target. When I change/edit the default page the variation is working, and after the timer job the changes are made to the en-us site.

But when I create a new page the variation is not working. When I open the the page that's not being transfered to the target site I see this notification (directly translated from Dutch): **source only, this page only exists on this site and is not available for translation on target sites**. I have tried to Google my issue but I can't find any information about this.

I even copied the default page but this gave me the same notification, this means it currently only works for one page. Has anybody any idea on how to solve this?

Edit 1:
I think I have found the solution, after I have checked in the page, Sharepoint gives me an option to make it a 'targetpage'. I think this will solve my problem. I will update this post when as soon as I know.

Comment: What is the difference between the pages that work and the ones that don't What's their content types?

Answer (score 1):

I have got the solution now. I have edited the page, and it's working now. The option to make it a target page is available after I have checked in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue and the solution was totally counter-intuitive :

- In my source site I had a page in version 3.0 (i.e. major version), not checked out, and approved. In other words: this page was **perfectly fit** to have its target version created on the variation site.
- **I had clicked on the "create target" button** in the ribbon and ran the **propagation job** in the central admin.
- yet the page was **not appearing** on the target site, no matter what. The variation log was indicating that it was processing this page, but that didn't mean much since the page had not been created on the target site, so the variation job was just leaving it untouched.

In the end, all I had to do was to **explicitly extract/check-in** that page one more time to "unlock" the propagation.